# Sparse Efficiency Warning from scipy file

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm getting the following error when trying to take the matrix exponential of a csc_array:

````
anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:103:
SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a
csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.```

  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
````

The code which produces the error is:

```py
csc_t_M = t_M.tocsc()
sigma = scipy.sparse.linalg.expm(-csc_t_M)
```

t_M is a dok_array.

It appears from the error that the problem is in the scipy.sparse package itself. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: The code has been added

Comment: I'm getting a warning when using `csr` format, telling me to use `csc`.  There are in-place operations that can give your warning, but I don't think `expm` does that.  Is your `scipy` an older version?

Answer (score 0):

`sparse.linalg.expm` is an complicated function, using, as the docs the `Pade approximation`.  From explorations years ago, I recall it involves a matrix inversion.

Let's test it with a small matrix:

```
In [60]: A = sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(3))

In [61]: A.A
Out[61]: 
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

With a `csr`:

```
In [63]: linalg.expm(A)
C:\Users\paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\dsolve\linsolve.py:318: SparseEfficiencyWarning: splu requires CSC matrix format
  warn('splu requires CSC matrix format', SparseEfficiencyWarning)
C:\Users\paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\dsolve\linsolve.py:215: SparseEfficiencyWarning: spsolve is more efficient when sparse b is in the CSC matrix format
  warn('spsolve is more efficient when sparse b '
Out[63]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Note the warning comes from a `spsolve` and `splu` step.

Paying attention to the warning, I don't get the warning:

```
In [64]: linalg.expm(A.tocsc())
Out[64]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>

In [65]: _.A
Out[65]: 
array([[2.71828183, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 2.71828183, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 2.71828183]])
```

It also works with a dense array:

```
In [66]: linalg.expm(A.A)
Out[66]: 
array([[2.71828183, 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 2.71828183, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 2.71828183]])
```

---

I get your warning if I try to change an element of a `csc` matrix:

```
In [86]: M = sparse.random(100,100,.2,'csc')

In [87]: M[50,50] = 12
C:\Users\paul\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py:82: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csc_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_intXint(row, col, x.flat[0])
```